# 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 while decode('utf-8') in python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

Today I was hit with strange error in my script:

```
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 21: invalid continuation byte
```

I'm reading data from socket `sock.recv` and result is `buff.decode('utf-8')` where buff is the returned data.

But today I found pretty much "unicorn" where one of the characters returned "▒" <-- this is what throw decode utf-8 into exception. Is there some pre process that would either remove or replace such a strange character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a second parameter for [`.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=decode#bytes.decode)  named `errors`. You can set it to `'ignore'` to ignore all non-utf8 characters, or set it to `'replace'` to replace them with the diamond question mark (�).

```
buff.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```